# Update post_content everytime a custom post is opened in backend

Tags: posts, filters

I need to implement a function that substitutes the post_content of the current custom post as soon as it is opened in admin editor. Its purpose is to have updated informations inside the content until the post becomes "published".

What is the correct action/hook that allows me to get the informations about the currently opened post and modify it?

I have developed this function but it is not working well:

```
function save_team() {
    $post = get_post();
    $ID_post = $post->ID;
    $team = get_post_meta ($ID_post, ‘hometeam’, true);
    if($post->post_type == "game" && $post->post_status == "draft"){
       $post_content = $post->post_content;
       //code that modifies post_content here by adding $team at some point
       $my_post = array(
          ‘ID’ => $ID_post,
          ‘post_content’ => $post_content,);
       wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`content_edit_pre`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_edit_pre) filter might be what you are looking for. This filters the content of a post before it's retrieved and output in the editor.

So you might be able to do this:

```
function save_team( $content, $post_id ) {
    $team = get_post_meta ($post_id , 'hometeam', true);
    if( get_post_type( $post_id ) == "game" && get_post_status( $post_id ) == "draft" ){
       //code that modifies post_content here by adding $team at some point
       $my_post = array(
          'ID' => $post_id,
          'post_content' => $content,);
       wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }
}
add_filter( 'content_edit_pre', 'save_team', 10, 2 );
```

The post ID and content are passed to this filter, so there's no need to use `get_post();` here.

As a side note, you should not use `‘` and `’` as quotations. Use `'` or `"` instead.

Comment: Thank you, it works! As an alternative, I tried the “edit_form_top” action and it seems to work too. Do you know which one is a better choice for this case?